# (Have always held) and (maintain)

Tags: phrase-usage, vocabulary

I've been told by my vocabulary book that it isn't correct to say:

> She **has always held** that we're related, but I'm not convinced.

And I should use **maintain** instead:

> She **maintains** that we're related, but I'm not convinced.

Since it's a phrase, not one word, I have difficulty searching that phrase in the dictionary to look up the meaning and examples for the second conviction. The book says it means [used for very firm beliefs], but it doesn't say anything why **have always held** couldn't be used there.

My point is, is it unnatural to say, for example:

> I've always held he's my brother.

Like when I say:

> I strongly believe if he's my brother. (Only if have I assumed it correct.)

Comment: You are right and your book is wrong. "She has always maintained" is perfectly fine. (It brings to mind the classic Mitch Hedberg line: "I used to do drugs. I still do, but I used to, too.")

Comment: @randomhead Sorry, What I'm asking here is She has always held _____. Thanks for your comment btw.

Comment: "hold (the belief that)..." and "maintain (that)..." are roughly the same. If you check dictionary definitions of [hold](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/hold) and [maintain](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/maintain), I think you can find the similarities.